# iPad repeatedly sets app local network permissions to off

Tags: ipad, network, permission

Since the introduction of the local network permission in iOS 14, my daughter's iPad can't connect to any other devices on the local network.

For example, previously she could play Minecraft and join a world on another device on the same network, but now they no longer show up. My iPad and my wife's still work as they did before.

I've noticed there are app-specific permissions for local network access, however if I access the permission via Settings -> Privacy -> Local network -> Minecraft, it's set to "On", whereas if I access it via Settings -> Minecraft -> Local network, it's set to "Off". If I set it to "On" there, it has always reset itself to "Off" the next time I look.

I've screenrecorded a [demo of the permission issue here](https://gfycat.com/defensivemisguidedfalcon).